# erl_nif_thread and erlang process communication

Tags: erlang, erlang-nif

Can we communicate with erl_nif thread created and normal erlang process? We can send messages from nif thread to erlang process using nif_send but can nif thread receive messages from any erlang process like normal erlang process do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a thread created with [`enif_thread_create`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_thread_create) is not an Erlang process and **cannot receive messages**.

You are probably trying to achieve too much with your NIF and might consider writing a [**linked in driver**](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html) instead, which can send messages and receive messages from Erlang.

Alternatively, you could use a conditional variable and/or a pipe in your native thread to wait for an event which would be generated by a NIF function called from the emulator whenever the message you are expecting is received. Indeed, unlike linked in drivers, you cannot use [the select interface from the emulator](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_driver.html#driver_select).